# Cómo hacer para que la pantalla gire al acceder desde una tablet o un celular a una web?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Esta es mi web y quiero hacer que cuando se acceda desde el celular o desde una tablet la pantalla gire 90 grados..

http://estudiomavericks.com/

---

Estoy buscando algo similar, pero no se si es correcto..

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) { 
    /* Smartphone view*/
    body {
  -webkit-transform:rotate (90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate (90deg);
  -o-transform:rotate (90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate (90deg);  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:650px) and (min-width:481px) { 
    /* Tablet view*/
    body {
 -webkit-transform:rotate (90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate (90deg);
  -o-transform:rotate (90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate (90deg);  
    }
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar probé ambos..

Answer (score 0):

Este código sólo funciona con algunos navegadores. Esta resuelto en base a la tecnología experimental [Screen.lockOrientation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      function reorient(e) {
        var portrait = (window.orientation % 180 == 0);
        $("body > div").css("-webkit-transform", !portrait ? "rotate(-90deg)" : "");
      }
      window.onorientationchange = reorient;
      window.setTimeout(reorient, 0);
    });
```

*Debes tener cargado jquery.*

Otro camino es detectar la orientación mediante CSS y generar un mensaje que solicite al usuario que modifique la orientación de su dispositivo móvil:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }
@media all and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Mucha suerte ;)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! por favor mira el [tour] y tambien [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Yo no veo un uso práctico a lo que tu pides, pero debería funcionar solo colocando esto:

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  }
}
```

Pero esto solo funcionará si el celular o smartphone tienen resoluciones menores a 1080px, por lo que otra sugerencia es mezclarlo con la detección de orientaciones que solo sucede en smartphones o tablets, así:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  }
}
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  }
}
```

Sería bueno que explicaras el porque, o que efecto quieres conseguir, ya que no considero esto práctico para nada, de pronto la solución es otra, pero estamos entendiendo otra cosa. Cualquier duda dejame tu comentario.